# issue with Enterprise Library rolling flat file trace listener

Tags: exception, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library rolling flat file trace listener to log my application error in a single text file. But, I am observing that it creates multiple files with some series of numbers appended to it instead of logging into one single file.

Please see my config settings and let me know is any changes needed

```
<listeners>
  <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234abccc"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234abccc"
    fileName="AppError.log" formatter="Text Formatter" filter="Error" />
</listeners>


<formatters>
  <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234abccc"
    template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
    name="Text Formatter" />
</formatters>

<categorySources>
  <add switchValue="All" name="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </add>
</categorySources>
<specialSources>
  <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
  <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
  <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </errors>
</specialSources>
<exceptionHandling>
<exceptionPolicies>
  <add name="Application Policy">
    <exceptionTypes>
      <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234abccc"
        postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
        <exceptionHandlers>
          <add name="Logging Exception Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234abccc"
            logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling"
            formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"
            priority="0" />
        </exceptionHandlers>
      </add>
    </exceptionTypes>
  </add>
</exceptionPolicies>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the numbers are appended to the log files is because it detects that a file already exists and the Rolling flat file trace listener increments the file number. Change the **rollFileExistsBehavior** setting to **Overwrite** to ensure the file you specify gets overwritten.